# Add multiple filter items for filtering Strapis v4 GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, strapi

I need to query the Strapi GraphQL with specific filter(s). Specifically, I need to add multiple category filters, depending on the user input.

While I currently have some javascript code which works (quite well actually) to construct the query string, I am wondering if the same is possible for GraphQL (using [node.js/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-http)).

This is an example of how the GraphQL filter should look like:

```
{
  requestedData
  (filters:
    {
      or: [
        {
          Italian: {Italian: {containsi: "some string"}},
          or: 
          [
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-1"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-2"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-3"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-4"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-5"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-6"}}},
          ]
        },
        {
          Slovenian: {Slovenian: {contains: "some string"}}
          or: 
          [
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-1"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-2"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-3"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-4"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-5"}}},
            {category: {category_name: {containsi: "category-6"}}},
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  )
```

As I have already said, I am currently constructing the filter with javascript.

Now, I'm wondering if this is also possible with GraphQL. The only thing similar I have currently found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894251/graphql-strapi-turn-full-array-of-filters-to-be-a-variable).

The example from the above link provides this code snippet:

```
query GetRecommendedStuff(
    $toolFilters: ToolFiltersInput
  ) {
    tools(
      filters: $toolFilters
    ) {
      data {
        attributes {
          toolname
          app_categories {
            data {
              attributes {
                category
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
//pass variables as a whole
variables: {toolFilters: {
            and: [
              { categories: { category: { eq: "" } } }
              { categories: { category: { eq: "" } } }
              { categories: { category: { eq: "" } } }
            ]
          }}
```

This implies that I would need to create as many `{ categories: { category: { eq: "" } } }` code blocks, as there are possbile categories.

So, the question is, can I create a "dynamic" filter with GraphQL, which would automatically create the needed amount of `category`s.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Edit: While I'm asking questions, is there a downside to querying the GraphQL backend from the browser (client)? Should I send the request to node.js and create the query / forward the request to Strapi, receive the reply and forwarding the reply back to the client?